# iPhone continually re-syncs custom lyrics for thousands of songs

Tags: iphone, mac, data-synchronization, music

Every time I sync my iPhone to my MacBook, approximately 18,000 of my 30,000 songs will re-run the “Syncing Lyrics” step, which significantly lengthens the time required to sync.

This re-sync occurs with every sync, whether done via USB cable or over wifi, whether I have added songs or edited songs or have made no changes to my Music library.

I do not have any Apple Music subscription/streaming/shopping services. All songs were imported manually into iTunes/Music over the last two decades.

Why does this happen, can it be stopped?

Comment: I have about 20K songs (but nowhere near the amount of lyrics) and I don’t have this issue.  Are you using some sort of tool to automate the downloading of lyrics?

Comment: I used to used Get Lyrical app [https://shullian.com/get_lyrical.php], though it quit working a few years ago. This sync error only began recently. I have manually checked a random handful of songs for special Unicode characters and found none.

Comment: Check the dates on the songs for when they were last modified

Comment: The songs resync lyrics every time no matter when they were last modified.

Comment: Given that, I'm thinking there could be an issue with the library and not with the files.  Can you back up the library, create a new blank one, copy about 100 or so songs with lyrics to the  new library and sync.  Then see if the problem persists.  It's a big ask but it appears you're syncing most/all files already so doing it once more isn't too catastrophic.